# Bounding boxes for individual contours except one color

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, contour

I have an image as below

[image]

I want to add bounding boxes for each of the regions as shown in the pic below using OpenCV & Python

[image]

I now how to find contours is the region is one colour. However, here I want to find contours for all non-Black regions. I am just not able to figure it out. Can anyone help?

Regrading some regions being regions being non-continuous (2 vertical lines on the left), you can ignore that. I will dilate & make them continuous.

Comment: You question is not clear. What contour is black? Guessing what you mean, convert your input to grayscale and threshold it. Then get the contours from that and then draw them on your original image.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean contours on everything except the background black color. Can you please let me know how to threshold(mask) everything except the black color? A link for another question will also be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, here is one way in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold to black and white
- Find external contours and their bounding boxes
- Draw the bounding box rectangles on a copy of the input
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('white_green.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]\

# get contour bounding boxes and draw on copy of input
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result = img.copy()
for c in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 0, 255), 1)

# view result
cv2.imshow("threshold", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save result
cv2.imwrite("white_green_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("white_green_bboxes.jpg", result)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Bounding Boxes:

[image]